# TSTableView - How to get tapped Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Has anybody successfully used TSTableView class in iOS applications?

I am trying to use this in one of our internal iOS app and now struggling to get the cell (TSTableViewCell) while tapping.

I have included the delegate methods.

```
- (void)tableView:(TSTableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtPath:(NSIndexPath *)rowPath
```

I would like to know, how to get the TSTableViewCell from didSelectRowAtPath function?

This may sound naive, but I could not find an answer.

Thanks in advance,
Karuthedan

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `indexPath` of the `tableCell` then you can simple get it by using `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method like below :

```
TSTableViewCell *thisCell = [yourTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

[Also check this](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/support/documentation/mobile-api-reference/Classes/TSTableView.html#//api/name/cellForRowAtIndexPath%3a)
**Hope this will help you**

Comment: Thanks for the response. I forgot to tell u that, I am using class TSTableView which I got from [here](https://github.com/Viacheslav-Radchenko/TSTableView). When I used this function, I got the the following exception. 
TSTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instanceI could not find any function called cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I saw the code, seems like you are dealing with some custom classes and if you check the delegate methods of TSTableView in your code there is no cellForRowAtIndexPath method in it. This is a custom class written by somebody you cannot do anything about it.